# Nginx stealing port 80!

Tags: 16.04, server, nginx

I'm getting a bit frustrated here.
I want port 80 for apache2 but nginx has stolen that port apparently.

I cant find where to remove this, the config for nginx say its listening to port 8000 and 8001

what i can find is that the PID/Program name "6021/nginx -g daemo" uses this as local adress 127.0.0.1:80.

When i do `systemctl status nginx` this is the info i get the following

```
    ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-05-05 01:33:40 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 6110 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6118 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6113 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6120 (nginx)
    Tasks: 17
   Memory: 8.9M
      CPU: 46ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─6120 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           ├─6121 nginx: worker process
           ├─6122 nginx: worker process
           ├─6123 nginx: worker process
           ├─6124 nginx: worker process
           ├─6125 nginx: worker process
           ├─6126 nginx: worker process
           ├─6127 nginx: worker process
           ├─6128 nginx: worker process
           ├─6129 nginx: worker process
           ├─6130 nginx: worker process
           ├─6131 nginx: worker process
           ├─6132 nginx: worker process
           ├─6133 nginx: worker process
           ├─6134 nginx: worker process
           ├─6135 nginx: worker process
           └─6136 nginx: worker process

May 05 01:33:40 Headsrv systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 05 01:33:40 Headsrv systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I have tried to run the command `grep -r "127.0.0.1:80" /*` and `grep -r "nginx -g daemo" /*` but no results, were the hell is nginx getting this port conf!?!
Any tips for troubleshooting is gold to me since i've run in to a wall now..

And before someone ask i have edited /etc/nginx/conf.d/wok.conf and /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to not using port 80

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with Debian 10 running openmediavault (OMV). After a restart (where the system had been running for months), the nginx instance that serves the OMV web interface on port 88 suddenly also served an nginx welcome page (from `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`) on port 80. Pretty annoying as I have a Nextcloud instance supposed to be available on that port.

The reason was that some time during some upgrade process, the following lines had been added to the end of the `http` config in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
...
http {
    ...

    client_max_body_size 0;

    server {
        client_max_body_size 0;
    }
}
...
```

Because the `server` part doesn't specify a `listen` directive, it [defaults to port 80](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen). And because no [`root`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive was specified, it [defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197550/883073) to `/usr/share/nginx/html` on my particular system.

**Edit** It turns out that I actually did the change myself when following [this guide](https://dbtechreviews.com/2020/03/how-to-install-nextcloud-on-openmedivault-5-with-remote-access-and-ssl/) to setup my system.

Answer (score 0):

What about in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`? Make sure that you comment out the ports that are listening from the default `nginx.conf` file. You only listed the locations in the `conf.d` sections...

There may be something like this in there:

```
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

Sorry would have just commented this, but don't have enough rep yet on askubunut.com

Comment: Did a "grep 80 /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" yields no hits.

Comment: Does a `grep -rnw /etc/nginx/ "80"` show anything in the NGINX folder using just 80? Im guessing that when you turn off the service for NGINX and restart apache, your apache works?

Comment: You mean `grep -rnw 80 /etc/nginx/`
It yields results


`/etc/nginx/koi-win:4:    80  88 ; # euro`
`/etc/nginx/koi-utf:10:    80  E282AC ; # euro` But thats nothing as i can see :)

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove the whole section:

```
http {
    ....
    ....
}
```

Then, restart nginx.